# Is this suitable to override CSS variables in custom CSS files

Tags: css

I have overridden the --bs-btn-font-size property into my custom CSS file
Is this suitable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the C in css stands for cascading, meaning that it is designed to handle such behavior. You're supposed to do it that way.